# hidden input "empty string" vs "null" Javascript, VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, invisible

I was attempting to JSON deserialize a collection in VB, as seen below.

```
Dim items = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(Page.Request.Params("Items"), New List(Of ItemDto))
```

There was an issue with the deserialization, the string "value" could not be null.

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

The collection "Items" was stored in a `<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Items" />` which translates to `<input type="hidden"....>`

however, if I did `$("#Items').val(null);` before it runs if there are no items and then it's working correctly.

The question is, why does `$("#Items").val();` show as "" before and "" after I've done `$("#Items").val(null);` and is there an invisible difference? like a zero width space?

I don't know why setting the collection to "null" has made the code work.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems by design. Looking at the [**jquery .val Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) it states that it only returns a `String or Number or Array` I assume that is why Null is returned as an empty string.

Comment: That would explain why null comes out as empty string, however, why would it be failing to deserialize when it previously came out as empty string before setting it to null?

Comment: Is your serialization not happening server side? If you open the browser debugger console (F12 in Chrome) check the network tab and in the header it should show you the value sent to the server. That way you can see what the difference is between the 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#Items").val();
```

never returns NULL and so empty string is returned and when you do

```
$("#Items').val(null);
```

it sets the value to "" or empty string and not null

so the following exception will not be thrown

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

because the value was set to "" by your JQuery and not NULL thus not raising the ASP.NET exception